# Responsive web design (Change layout on resize)

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm a bit lost with responsive web design, I can use media queries to include a style sheet for a specific size. So for instance a screen at 600px will use a specific stylesheet while a larger screen will user a totally different one. The issue I'm having is my layout doesn't change on resize. It does however look correct if it's at the appropriate size and reloaded, but it doesn't change layouts dynamically on resize..

What am I doing wrong?

This is how I'm including my stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 600px)" />
```

Comment: You'll have to post some code or a demo. We're blind here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do that obviously. I figured out my issue though, I needed to have one main style sheet with my media queries inside.

Comment: Great news. Please close/delete your question or post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, I needed to have one main style sheet with my media queries inside.